# React Native useState and useEffect Interaction

Tags: typescript, react-native

I've got a functional component with state. I'm also using `useEffect` to call a function which updates the state. (I've simplified this case as much as I can, but to give an explanation of "why," I'm trying to use `AsyncStorage` which requires the use of an asynchronous function to handle its `Promises`.) The interaction of `useEffect` and the state is confusing me.

1. I don't know why my state `value` is null immediately after it is being set in my update function.
2. I don't know why, after my `value` is registered in the state, it is read as a plain `Object` even though I've provided the `SpecialObject` type when calling the hook.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { ReactElement } from "react-native/node_modules/@types/react";
import { Text, View } from "react-native";
import { plainToClass } from "class-transformer";

export default function ExampleUseEffectStateComponent(): ReactElement {
  const [value, setValue] = useState<SpecialObject>(null);
  
  const updateMyObject = () => {
    const myObject: SpecialObject = new SpecialObject("abc", 123);
    setValue(myObject);
    // ❓ Why is this null?
    console.log("value after being set in function: " + value);
  };
  // ❓ Why is this a plain Object?
  console.log("Outside of function, plain Object: " + value);
  console.log("Outside of function, casted: " + plainToClass(SpecialObject, JSON.stringify(value)));
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      updateMyObject();
    }, 2500);
  }, []);

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>hello</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

class SpecialObject {
  private id: string;
  private value: number;

  constructor(id: string, value: number) {
    this.id = id;
    this.value = value;
  }
}
```

And when I render this in an app, I get the following output in the console:

```
Outside of function, plain Object: [object Object]
Outside of function, casted: {"id":"abc","value":123}
value after being set in function: null
```

So `value` *is* getting updated, at least, but shouldn't `value` not be null immediately after I set it? And shouldn't `value` not require me to re-cast it in order for it to be recognized as something other than a plain `Object`?

Comment: There are a few problems with your code. First, you need to clearInterval. Second, this is a setInterval not a setTimeOut which means that every 2.5 seconds, you're setting your state again with a new object. Third, since you're using a functional component, why create a class specialObject? Just create a type specialObject and use this.

Comment: 1. Interesting. I'll do some research on `clearInterval`. 2. In my actual code, I'm not actually creating a new instance in my real code; this is just an example to reproduce my issue. In reality, I'm dealing with a `Promise` returned from AsyncStorage in which case I believe I do want to continually check the stored value in case it gets updates. 3. I'm using a character because I want the fields to have private access and protect the fields behind getters/setters. Shouldn't this still work with a class? I've also tried this workflow with a type and I'm still getting the same issue.

Comment: I looked into `clearInterval` and it looks like it just stops the interval from executing. While  it may be good practice and I may end up doing that eventually, I don't think it helps with either of the two primary questions in my post.

Comment: I meant clearing the interval when the component unmounts. Also, the console log that says "value after being set in function: " shows the previous value not the updated one. You can see the updated on on the next render. Try putting that same console log under the useState outside of the function, and the value might be updating correctly without you knowing it

Comment: Yeah, you're right about the value being null within the function. I also did some more reading and found a video that mentioned that this value isn't updated until the `useEffect` finishes executing. Apparently until `useEffect` finishes executing, the value continues to be the previous value, in this case null. So that answers that, but I guess I'm still trying to figure out why the value is losing its class/type.